# Left outer join funny results

Tags: sql-server

please take a look at below 2 queries regarding left outer join and tell me why there are differences.
`Query 1` returns 1489 rows:

```
SELECT distinct a.GMS_MATERIALNUMBER,a.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, b.LDMC
FROM [AP_GDC2_PREPARATION_TEST].[dbo].[GDM_AUTOPULL] a
left outer join  [AP_GDC2_STAGING_TEST].[dbo].[CFS_DIS_LDMC] b on
a.GMS_MATERIALNUMBER = b. GMS_MATERIALNUMBER and b.SAP_COMPANY_CODE= '1715'
and a.CFS_ORGANIZATION_CODE like 'rd_kr'
```

`Query 2` returns only 295 rows which gives the same number of rows as when i do a simple select * from a where CFS_ORGANIZATION_CODE like 'rd_kr'

```
SELECT distinct a.GMS_MATERIALNUMBER,a.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, b.LDMC
FROM [AP_GDC2_PREPARATION_TEST].[dbo].[GDM_AUTOPULL] a
left outer join  [AP_GDC2_STAGING_TEST].[dbo].[CFS_DIS_LDMC] b on
a.GMS_MATERIALNUMBER = b. GMS_MATERIALNUMBER and b.SAP_COMPANY_CODE= '1715'
where a.CFS_ORGANIZATION_CODE like 'rd_kr'
```

Basically `query 2` is the result i wanted, but my question is why `query 1` does not work? how exactly does the SQL server work in the background when it comes to the `ON` clause in the `left outer join` ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Both are literally different.

The first query does the **filtering of table before the joining of tables** will take place.

The second one **filters from the total result after the joining the tables** is done.

---

Here's an example

Table1

```
ID   Name
1    Stack
2    Over 
3    Flow
```

Table2

```
T1_ID   Score
1       10
2       20
3       30
```

---

In your first query, it looks like this,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.Score
FROM    Table1 a
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b
           ON a.ID = b.T1_ID AND
              b.Score >= 20
```

What it does is before joining the tables, the records of `table2` are filtered first by the score. So the only records that will be joined on table1 are

```
T1_ID   Score
2       20
3       30
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4fd/2)

because the `Score` of `T1_ID` is only 10. The result of the query is

```
ID   Name    Score
1    Stack   NULL
2    Over    20
3    Flow    30
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4fd/3)

---

While the second query is different.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.Score
FROM    Table1 a
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b
           ON a.ID = b.T1_ID
WHERE   b.Score >= 20
```

It joins the records first whether it has a matching record on the other table or not. So the result will be

```
ID   Name    Score
1    Stack   10
2    Over    20
3    Flow    30
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4fd/5)

and the filtering takes place `b.Score >= 20`. So the final result will be

```
ID   Name    Score
2    Over    20
3    Flow    30
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4fd/4)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because you made an `LEFT JOIN`.
So you get all rows from your first table and all that match from your second table.

In the second query you `JOIN` first, and after you set your `WHERE` statement to reduce the result.